# How do I remove construction glue from brick?

Tags: brick, removal, glue

I just removed glued-on paneling from an interior brick wall. Now, I have the task of removing the glue from said brick. What is the best method of doing so? I know there's no getting around the use of a scraper, obviously, but wanted to get input from you all :)

*Click for full size*

[image: Construction glue on brick]

Comment: I've heard of using a heat gun to make the glue pliable again in combination with a sturdy scrapper or using an acid mixture (**NOT** my first choice, by the way!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comment said, a heat gun may make scraping this off much easier. First, try scraping some off without a heat gun.  You might get lucky and it might "break" off the surface in large solid pieces.  If it does, the heat gun might make it more difficult.  If it does not come off easily, then I'd try the heat gun.

Start a low temperature and work your way up gradually until the adhesive softens up; you don't want to burn it, just soften it up. Please beware that heating this adhesive might release harmful vapors.  Make sure your area is **well** ventilated when doing this. You might even opt to wear a respirator.

I would personally stay away from solvents in this case especially if you do not know what type of adhesive it is.

Comment: Steven, thanks for the comment. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, the best route in this case has been a scrapper and a good ol' hammer and chisel :)

Comment: Beer + Friends always makes jobs easier :)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out a hammer & chisel worked great! Just took some time *(just like anything else does)*

[image: Mud & tap 2]